# What kind of circuit board standoff is this?

Tags: pcb

I have a PCB with several broken standoffs like this:

[image]

The bottom of the part is where it broke - it used to be a plastic 'foot' that would have been relatively flush to the case that the PCB is mounted in.

It looks like you'd assemble this by inserting from the bottom, first through the case and then through the PCB. It snaps into both.

I've searched on ebay, images, other shopping sites, etc. and haven't found anything similar; probably I'm not using the right search terms. There are plenty of standoffs of other types, but none with this dual snap-in design that I've found. (Not even certain that "standoff" is the correct term).

Thanks

Comment: I think standoff is the correct term.   when searching for a replacement I would first measure the two hole sizes it needs to fit.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32844434973.html

Comment: @Jasen that's very similar! is "reverse locking" the key term there? I'm not sure what portion of this is considered to be reversed though.

Comment: the bottom clip is reversed from the top clip, compared to a regular double-ended clip-in spacer

Comment: Unfortunately product descriptions on Aliexpress are often word salad poorly translated from Chinese, so I wodn't put too much trust in the actual text.

Comment: Press-fit, side-lock, lock-in PCB spacers/supports. Look at the Essentra catalog. Google-fu Master tip: Use google images with a crappy search term to find better search terms.

Comment: Richco, Micro Plastics, and others make them.  Digi-Key, Mouser, Newark, allied.  "PC board standoff.  Lotsa options for the foot, height, pcb hole diameter, chassis hole diameter, etc.  Some use a square foot/hole to prevent rotation.

Comment: @DKNguyen I don't think its side lock, don't those slide in sideways?

Comment: @DKNguyen re: image search I didn't think to try that since it was a broken part but its a good suggestion! thanks

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs You don't enter in the image. You enter in your best guess at a search term and find what websites with a matching image actually calls them.

Comment: @DKNguyen they also have a search-for-actual-image feature which is useful in some cases. But it didn't recognize this photo probably for a # of reasons included that it is broken.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Image search doesn't work so well for real photos. Works great for animated screen caps though

Comment: @DKNguyen I've had some luck with it on photos, but its very inconsistent. It can sometimes find the original (or at least other copies) of an exact photograph, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

Fairly similar to [these](https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/70944xx00_3_4.pdf) Würth products which Würth calls a "Snap-on stop spacer, reverse mounted". Other manufacturers may have somewhat different names.

[image]

You can also check other manufacturers at any distributor such as Digikey.